# How to delete a const char* created with _strdup()

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, char

I am using the following piece of code in Visual Studio to store a constructor parameter char* and delete it in the deconstruction of my class.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(const char *fn) {
        myChar = _strdup(fn);
    }

    ~A() {
        delete[] myChar;
    }

    char *myChar;
};


int main()
{
    A myA("lala");
    myA.~A();

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); //leak detector
}
```

If I do not use the delete[] myChar, I create memory leak. If I use it i get this unknown error in debuging.

[image]

Whats the correct way to do that?

---

After changing `delete[]` to `free`:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIbNo.png]

Comment: What does the [`_strdup` documentation say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strdup-wcsdup-mbsdup?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: You do realize that after you manually invoke a destructor yourself, when `main()` exits the object gets destroyed, invoking its destructor again? What do you expect to accomplish by deleting the same pointer twice? Even without any memory allocation or deallaction, above, the above code invokes the destructor twice for the same object. This is undefined behavior. C++ does not work this way. Why don't you try checking for your memory leaks ***after normally destroying the object***?

Comment: Please simply use `std::string` instead of `new`/`delete`/`malloc`/`free` and the C string library. This will solve all your memory issues. (Assuming you also stop calling destructors manually, there is almost never a reason to do that.)

Comment: Please don't fix your mistakes that are relevant to the question in the question code. It invalidates the answers. I have reverted your last edit.

Comment: I have added your new image at the end of your question. Please don't fix the code itself. You can add additional information at the end.

Comment: thanks, I hadnt realised thats wrong.
thanks everybody. sorry, that was pretty nubby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems here.

1. **You `delete[]` instead of `free`.**

   `strdup` comes from the C library. [The documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) tells us how to clean it up.

   Microsoft's similar `_strdup` [works the same way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strdup-wcsdup-mbsdup?view=vs-2019).

   *You must read the documentation for functions that you use*, particularly if you're having trouble with them. That is why it is there.
2. **You invoke the destructor of `A` manually, when you shouldn't.**

   The object has automatic storage duration, and will be destroyed automatically. When you for some reason call the destructor yourself, that means it'll be ultimately called *twice*. That means the erroneous deallocation call `delete[] myChar` will also be called twice, which is clearly worng.
3. **Your object's copy semantics are broken.**

   Okay, so you don't copy it here. But any object that manages memory should follow the rule of zero, the rule of three, or the rule of five.
4. **You're checking for leaks too early.**

   `myA` is still alive when you call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`, so of course it's going to see that it hasn't been destroyed/freed yet, and deem that to be a memory leak. You're supposed to call that function after you've attempted to rid yourself of all your resources, not before.

Here's your directly fixed code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(const char *fn) {
        myChar = _strdup(fn);
    }

    A(const A& other) {
        myChar = _strdup(other.myChar);
    }

    A& operator=(const A& other) {
        if (&other != this) {
           free(myChar);
           myChar = _strdup(other.myChar);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    ~A() {
       free(myChar);
    }

    char *myChar;
};


int main()
{
    {
       A myA("lala");
    }

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); //leak detector
}
```

And here's what it should have been:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>   // for std::move
#include <crtdbg.h>  // for _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks

class A
{
public:
    A(std::string str) : m_str(std::move(str)) {}

private:
    std::string str;
};

int main()
{
   {
      A myA("lala");
   }

   _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); // leak detector
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different allocation schemes out there. Too many to just guess or assume how to free things. So you first look up the documentation on the function. Even just googling something like "msdn _strdup" often gets there or close (for stuff that comes with Windows / Visual Studio / Microsoft).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strdup-wcsdup-mbsdup?view=vs-2019

> The _strdup function calls malloc to allocate storage space for a copy of strSource and then copies strSource to the allocated space.

and

> Because _strdup calls malloc to allocate storage space for the copy of strSource, it is good practice always to release this memory by calling the free routine on the pointer that's returned by the call to _strdup.

So you need to use `free`